# iPhone: Is my crash log being symbolicated correctly?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

My understanding is that XCode 4 (which is what I'm using) has automatic crash log symbolication. And, sure enough, it looks like the Apple API stuff is getting symbolicated automatically. But the stuff related to my application is just a bunch of numbers. So it doesn't really help me determine the source of the crash in my application. I guess I'm wondering if this is correct or is there another step that I have to perform to get the symbols from my program? (And if so, how?)

At any rate, a sample crash log looks like this:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3569b974 strchr + 12
1   My Mobile App                   0x0000c4e0 0x1000 + 46304
2   My Mobile App                   0x0000b814 0x1000 + 43028
3   My Mobile App                   0x0000b440 0x1000 + 42048
4   My Mobile App                   0x00016df2 0x1000 + 89586
5   My Mobile App                   0x00016fec 0x1000 + 90092
6   Foundation                      0x341c48f0 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidReceiveData:originalLength:] + 144
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this site ,

you can manually run symbolicatecrash "crash file" "your symbol file"

http://kevincupp.com/2011/05/12/symbolicating-ios-crash-logs.html